# Can I search folders with php?

Tags: php, search

I have a folder in my root with several subfolders, containing images, with file names eg.: product_109847_300x220. All images names contains the image size (eg.: 300x220).

I'd like to search the folders with PHP, and print all images that have "300x220" in it's file name. How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: With *dir function in php (opendir, readdir, ...) and you manipulate the filename to find "300x200"

Comment: RTFM http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: please just search once before you ask. It is even faster than registering with stackoverflow. http://google.com/?q=search+directory+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/tmp");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
   // do your string comparison on file name here and process it
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [glob](https://www.php.net/glob):

```
$files = glob('folder/*300x220*');
```

This will get all files containing 300x220 in the folder directory. You can also use glob to list all directories in a folder but i'll leave that up to you.

Comment: please note that glob is a memory hogger. if you have large amounts of files, or a low amount of memory allowed, it will kill off your script.